# How to fill "column B" based on value in "column A" when the column has object dtype in python pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I have a CSV file which I imported as a pandas dataframe.
I want to create and fill up a column based on some specific terms in another column.
The column that has all those values is an **object** dtype. It has values like:

```
ABC|MNO - 2017 - Trial|1|Random|xyz|RUN|Google|1x1|A10001-21|SD|GH|PRIME - 2017 - Big - This is For Example
```

The code I was using is:

```
def new(row):
  if row.str.contains("PRIME"):
      return 'A'
  if row.str.contains("Random"):
      return 'B'
  if row.str.contains("Google"):
      return 'C'

df['X'] = df['Y'].apply (lambda row: new (row))
```

This code is giving me following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I think it is because **Column X** has **Object** dtype.

I tried converting it to a string using the code:

```
df['Y'] = df['Y'].astype('str')
```

but it doesn't work. Then I tried splitting it using the following code:

```
df['Y_new'] = df['Y'].str.split(r'([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?])')
```

But it converted all the values to **NaN**.  How should I do this?

Comment: Make sure you understand what `row` is inside your function.  If necessary add a `print(type(row))` statement to the function.  If `df['Y']` is object dtype, then the type of `row` could be different each call.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
    def new(row):
      if row.contains("PRIME"):
         return 'A'
      if row.contains("Random"):
         return 'B'
      if row.contains("Google"):
         return 'C'
```

Comment: tried, but it returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`